# React Native iOS build failed after installing react-native-immediate-phone-call; Android works fine

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Hey I have a problem with react-native-immediate-phone-call package. Android build works perfect, however on iOS while using Mac M1 build fails with error:

```
** BUILD FAILED ** The following build commands failed: CompileC /Users/michalpawlowski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuManager-dhwvpfsdgqkknsdamgvddtqaipyh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RNImmediatePhoneCall.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNImmediatePhoneCall.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNImmediatePhoneCall.o /Users/michalpawlowski/Documents/GitHub/manager-app/ManagerApp/node_modules/react-native-immediate-phone-call/ios/RNImmediatePhoneCall/RNImmediatePhoneCall.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNImmediatePhoneCall' from project 'RNImmediatePhoneCall') (1 failure)
```

When I delete the package from the Libraries folder in XCode project builds successfully.

```
react-native: 0.71.4
react-native-immediate-phone-call: 2.0.0
XCode: 14.2
Macbook Pro M1
macOS Ventura 13.0.1
```

I've probably scoured almost the entire internet in last 3 days searching for solution to this issue, however none of them worked... Any up-to-date ideas?

Comment: Hi, please share more of the build error

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't have the CocoaPods dependencies installed.

Just run:
`npx pod-install ios`